# SQL Query How to Find Data for Last Few Months in January (mixed years) SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, date-range, getdate

I'm creating a query to pull records for the Last 3 Months. The problem I am having is when the last x months cross over to the previous year. I think I have a solution, but I feel like there's a better way?

Field: **asiplayer.date_used** is a DateTime field.

The below code seems to be working (but how do I test for January in July?)

Is there a better way? What if it was the last 6 months, would I just continue this code?

```
WHERE
-- ACTIVE LIST (LAST 3 MONTHS)
(

(   --Current Month is Not January or February, so all 3 months are in current year

        MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NOT IN (1,2) 
        AND MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) >= MONTH(DateAdd(month,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
        AND YEAR(asiplayer.date_used) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
) 


    OR  --It's January so some of the months are last year

(           
        --Get November and December of the Previous Year    
        (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 1 AND   (MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) = MONTH(DateAdd(month,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) OR MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) = MONTH(DateAdd(month,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)))
            AND YEAR(asiplayer.date_used) = YEAR(DateAdd(year,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        )

        OR  
            --Get January of the Current Year
            (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 1 
            AND MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) = 1 
            AND YEAR(asiplayer.date_used) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            )

)   


    OR --It's February so some of the months are last year


(           
        --Get December of the Previous Year 
        (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 2 AND MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) = MONTH(DateAdd(month,-2,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) 
            AND YEAR(asiplayer.date_used) = YEAR(DateAdd(year,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
        )

        OR  
            --Get January & February of the Current Year
            (MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = 2 
            AND MONTH(asiplayer.date_used) IN (1,2) 
            AND YEAR(asiplayer.date_used) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
            )

)   

)
```

Comment: DATEDIFF(MONTH, asiplayer.date_used, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <=3

Comment: holy smokes Serg, I had a feeling there was an easier way, but not THAT EASY! Thanks! Geesh, so much wasted code and time on my part. :|

Comment: Yeh, it happens other day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serg provided the answer:

DATEDIFF(MONTH, asiplayer.date_used, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <=3